# Replace enquanto realiza filtragem

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando realizar um replace enquanto faço a filtragem de itens da minha api. Gostaria de remover os `ATIVO` do `NameChange` quando o ATIVO for encontrado na string e retornar o nameChange.
Segue o código que eu estava tentando utilizar para realizar a ação:

```
const filteredName = search.length > 0
    ? changeNames.filter(nameChange => 
        nameChange.name.toLowerCase().includes(search).includes('ATIVO') 
        ? nameChange.name.replace(' ATIVO', '') 
        : nameChange.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
    : []
```

Comment: tem o array exemplo?

Comment: @novic, infelizmente não